Audit activities by Entra registered app's Service Principal
I know we can see sign-in logs and that is fantastic.  I searched, did see this - Azure AD - How to check whether a service principal is being used? - but I'm hoping to go beyond that.  I have an app that signs in with client credential successfully, but then is not performing the hoped activities against mailboxes in Exchange Online.
I've found no results in Purview's Audit Logs area, nor in Sentinel using the query below, where I do see lots of audited activity for mostly only Microsoft's own Service Principals (e.g., "Device Registration Service", "Office 365 Exchange Online", "Azure MFA StrongAuthenticationService").
Does anyone know of any way to check for attempted calls to Exchange Online's EWS by an app registration's SPN?
We're testing with application access policies, RBAC for Applications in EXO, and even with neither of these.  Our healthcare related application is signing in successfully every time we try to test it, but that is the only signs of activity we can see.  No failed nor successful operations within the mailbox audit logs, nothing in unified audit log, don't know what else to do, but it seems like I'm stuck in a blind spot.
